# Runtime error with multidimensional array data members

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have started developing a program to solve a sudoku, and I created a class called SudokuSolver to encapsulate the "sudoku solver". There is a multidimensional array in the class to store the data for the sudoku. The program compiled just fine, but when I ran it, a runtime exception is thrown indicating there is a access violation, at the line pointed by the arrow:

```
class SudokuSolver
{
private:
    int sudoku[9][9];
    bool valid(int sodoku[9][9]);
    bool solve(int x,int y);
    bool repeat(int x,int y,int num);
public:
    SudokuSolver();
    bool setSudoku(int sudoku[9][9]);
    bool solveSudoku();
    void printSudoku()const;
};

SudokuSolver::SudokuSolver()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;++i)
        for(int j = 0;j < 9;++i)
------->--->--->    sudoku[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what is going on over here??? This is my assignment so it is very urgent.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about a simple typo. See meta discussion at 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did ++i in the second loop.

```
SudokuSolver::SudokuSolver()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;++i)
        for(int j = 0;j < 9;++i)  //Your error is here..
          sudoku[i][j] = 0;
}
```

should be:

```
SudokuSolver::SudokuSolver()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;++i)
        for(int j = 0;j < 9;++j)
          sudoku[i][j] = 0;
}
```